# Django Form with dependent ForeignKey forms on one Page

Tags: python, django

Good day, I am trying to implement django with a dependent foreignkey forms on one page. I have three moodels Store, Product, and ProductClothing. They are all ForeignKey related respectively. Users get to create their store seperately, and are redirected to the store detail view where they will now have to upload Products. But this time, I want them to upload both products and product clothing at once. Below is my models.py and views.py of what I have currently on the store detail view. Also the error I get is:

```
error.py
NOT NULL constraint failed: product_productclothing.product_id
```

```
models.py
class Store(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name', unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, verbose_name=_("Regular price"))

class ProductClothing(models.Model):
    CLOTHING_GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male',),
        ('F', 'Female',),
        ('U', 'Unisex',),
    )
    CLOTHING_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('dress', 'Dresses',),
        ('fabric', 'Fabrics',),
        ('shirt', 'Shirts',),
        ('suit', 'Suits',),
        ('tshirt', 'T-Shirts',),
        ('base_layers', 'Base_Layers',),
        ('blazer', 'Blazers',),
    )

    product = models.OneToOneField(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CLOTHING_GENDER_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    clothing_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=CLOTHING_TYPE_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.title
```

```
views.py
@login_required
def store_dashboard_view(request, slug):
    store = get_object_or_404(Store, slug=slug)
    new_product = None
    product_clothing = None
    
    if request.user.profile == store.owner:
        if request.method == 'GET':
            product_form = ProductForm()
            product_clothing_form = ProductClothingForm()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            product_form = ProductForm(data=request.POST)
            product_clothing_form = ProductClothingForm(data=request.POST)
            
            if product_form.is_valid() and product_clothing_form.is_valid():
                new_product = product_form.save(commit=False)
                product_clothing_form.save(commit=False)
                new_product.store = store
                new_product.owner = request.user.profile
                product = product_form.save()
                product = product
                product_clothing_form.product = product
                product_clothing_form.save()
                print(request.user.first_name)
                return redirect('/')
                

        context = {
            "object":store,
            "form": product_form,
            "product_clothing_form": product_clothing_form
        }
        return render(request, "store/store-dashboard.html", context)
    else:
        return redirect('store:store-detail-view', slug=store.slug)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to Change this part

```
        if product_form.is_valid() and product_clothing_form.is_valid():
            new_product = product_form.save(commit=False)
            product_clothing_form.save(commit=False)
            new_product.store = store
            new_product.owner = request.user.profile
            product = product_form.save()
            product = product
            product_clothing_form.product = product
            product_clothing_form.save()
            print(request.user.first_name)
            return redirect('/')
```

to

```
        if product_form.is_valid() and product_clothing_form.is_valid():
            new_product = product_form.save(commit=False)
            product_clothing_form = product_clothing_form.save(commit=False)
            new_product.store = store
            new_product.owner = request.user.profile
            new_product.save() #this is correct your mistake was here
            print(new_product)
            product_clothing_form.product = new_product
            product_clothing_form.save()
            print(request.user.first_name)
            return redirect('/')
```

Comment: It still returned the same error where it says:
NOT NULL constraint failed: product_productclothing.product_id

Comment: @Arthur are you sure you wrote exactly what i wrote here ? Try `print(product)` to see what you got and tell me it please ?

Comment: Yes, I just copied it and used it directly.

Comment: @Arthur add `print(product)` after you declare the variable `product=new_product.save()` , what did you get ?

Comment: I just printed product now and I got None

Comment: @Arthur that is interesting try to use the new code i wrote.i have updated my answer. and tell me what did you got in `print(new_product)`.

Comment: All thanks to you Amadou, I really appreciate you. I used the updated code and did product_clothing_form.product = new_product instead of putting product as a variable just like I did earlier. Code works now like, Merci Boucoup

Comment: @Arthur De rien bro .do not forget to accept and mark it as the answer.

Comment: Sure, I just did, thanks.